# Автоматическое удаление записей таблицы

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Как реализовать автоматическое удаление записей, старше 1 недели, из определённой таблицы базы MS SQL?

Comment: С ним у меня проблема, не хочет он запускаться и вообще работать

Comment: А что, триггеры тут не подойдут, раз уж с агентом проблемы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно установить джоб, который будет удалять записи старше одной недели. С нужной периодичностью (мы, например, на ночь ставим, потому что большие таблицы).

Comment: А как сделать задачу именно для удаления, насчёт планировщика задач - это я уже понял...

Comment: Прямо в джобе можно написать запрос, который будет удалять записи.

Comment: Тогда, мне нужна помощь по составлению запроса: база на компе NIKITA-PC, Имя Базы: Jobs, Таблица Vacansies, Записи нужно удалить с полем Weeks = 4

Comment: Попробуйте

    use Jobs
    go
    delete from Vacansies where Weeks = 4

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать хранимую процедуру и отправить её в job

```
    DECLARE @Num int, @Count int, @DbName sysname, @Date datetime, @ScriptTemplate nvarchar(2000), @Script nvarchar(2000)

    SET @Date = DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()) -- 1 month ago
    ну а дальше разберётесь?
```